# What is the good way of storing software version for python CLI ? (<app> --version)

Tags: python, command-line-interface, design-guidelines

Python CLI application display version using the `--version` argument.
What is the right way to store that information ? Argparse has an argument for that

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 2.0')
parser.parse_args(['--version'])
```

But I am not convinced it is the right way to do it. I'm thinking about storing the version in a file so it can be maintained by the build pipeline but it should be protected so users can't modify it.

Comment: Why would it matter or be your problem if the users *did* modify it?

Comment: It seems wrong to me. Softwares and OS won't allow you to modify the version file. Why would my software allow that ?

Answer (score 1):

I also create a `version.py` file, but my content is even simpler:

`version = 'develop'`

The clue is, that this one-line-file is replaced in my pipeline with the actual version coming from git tags. So every version provided by a pipeline build will have something like `version = "v1.0.23"` in it.
Then I can simply do an `from version import version` wherever I need it.

Example for gitlab ci:

```
  # set version
  - VERSION=$(git describe --tags)
  - echo "version = '$VERSION'" > version.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Version.py file and imported it to the main Code.if its dev + will add to version and if it is exe the + will be ignored.

The file Content sample:

```
import sys
VERSION = 'V' + '0' + '.' + '3'
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False): #adding + for dev and Build for exe
    VERSION = VERSION + ' '
else:
    VERSION = VERSION + ' +'
```

Comment: Thank you ! I like the idea ! but why do you add "+" at the end of non-frozen app ?

Comment: Why *any* of the concatenation, why not `VERSION = 'V0.3'`, and why add a trailing space?

Comment: it's your wish , it if it is a minor change i will increment digit after decimal point. or major i will increment the first digit . thats it